# javascript collision detection with css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, collision-detection

I have the following "game":

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvz420/a7x12j9w/)

```
function update() {
  coyote.applyForce(gravity);
  coyote.edges();
  coyote.update();
  cactus.update();
  if (coyote.intersects(cactus)){
    alert("colision");
  }
}
```

the problem is that when coyote jumps, the div increase its size and there are some blank spots that cause collision too.

Is there any way to improve the collision detection? I have tried to implement inner hitbox but I didn't figure out how to.

Comment: Yes. Compute the intersection. Use a canvas of that size to render the particular areas from both elements and fetch the raw pixel datas for each one of the two elements. Now search the data ,pixel by pixel (4 byte), for a point where both arrays contain a value (other than 0)

Answer (score 1):

It took a while to understand what you where doing.

But if you take a static width and height for your player. It should fix your problem.

```
constructor(){
    this.coyote = new Entity();
    this.coyote.pos.set(0,222);
    this.coyote.vel.set(0,0);
    this.coyote.acc.set(0,0);
    this.coyote.width = 78;
    this.coyote.height = 128;
    this.isGrounded = true;
    this.state = States.RUNNING;
}

intersects(other) {
    let div = document.getElementById("player");
    let left = this.coyote.pos.x;
    let right = this.coyote.width;
    let top = this.coyote.pos.y;
    let bottom = this.coyote.height;
    let oLeft = other.left;
    let oRight = other.right;
    let oTop = other.top;
    let oBottom = other.bottom;
    return !(left > oRight || right < oLeft || top > oBottom || bottom < oTop);
}
```

This should work out for you.

Tips:
 1. use as starter a canvas.
 2. the most important is readable code.
 3. comments and summaries

Comment: In this work I'm not allowed to use canvas it would be so much easy haha, also yeah the original code is segmented in multiple js files but jsfiddle didn't allow that (as far as i know)